# Event delegation gives null value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple select menu:

```
<select id="ind">
  <option id="a">Parent A</option>
  <option id="b">Parent B</option>
  <option id="c">Parent C</option>
</select>

<div id="buttons">
</div>
```

And I am using an array of data to create some dynamic buttons. The goal is that each button will be able to trigger a change in the `select` menu by using the `id` of the button itself. For that, I am using event delegation.

```
var data = ["a", "b", "c"];

function changeValue() {

  $("#ind").val(this.id).trigger("change");
}

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  $('#buttons').append("<button class='btnParent' type='button' id='" 
+ data[i] + "'>" + data[i] + "</button>");
}

$("#buttons").on("click", ".btnParent", changeValue);
```

However, when I click on the buttons, the value being passed to the select is `null`, so nothing really happens.

I think I am using delegation as intended (hopefully). Is there any fix or alternative?

Edit: Forgot to add [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rubenwap/rs92qfLg/)

Comment: I just realized about the `id` and `value` problem. But other than that, I am scratching my eyes trying to find duplicate `id`...

Comment: @eisbehr : the dynamically added button and option tag have the same id

Comment: Ok!! That's right... duplicate ids finally... thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set `value` attribute to `option` not `id`.

```
<select id="ind">
  <option value="a">Parent A</option>
  <!----  ^^^^^^ ------------------->
  <option value="b">Parent B</option>
  <!----  ^^^^^^ ------------------->
  <option value="c">Parent C</option>
  <!----  ^^^^^^ ------------------->
</select>
```

```js
var data = ["a", "b", "c"];

function changeValue() {

  $("#ind").val(this.id).trigger("change");
}

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  $('#buttons').append("<button class='btnParent' type='button' id='" + data[i] + "'>" + data[i] + "</button>");
}

$("#buttons").on("click", ".btnParent", changeValue);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ind">
  <option value="a">Parent A</option>
  <option value="b">Parent B</option>
  <option value="c">Parent C</option>
</select>

<div id="buttons">

</div>
```

Comment: Totally right, the `value` and `id` mixup was what was being problematic.